# Combinatorics - The Students and Grades Problem

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are $20$ students in a classroom, $10$ males and 10 females. How many ways can a teacher distribute exactly $5$ As, $6$ Bs, $5$ Cs, $2$ Ds, and $2$ Fs to the students?

My Logic: $(20 C 5)(15 C 6)(9 C 5)(4 C 2)(2 C 2)$ seems the like the most intuitive answer but then this answer ignores the number of males and females in the class. Rather, if we treat the whole classroom as our sample, then we avoid any extra casework. I may be missing something here though so feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: I agree with your logic, since human beings are distinguishable. Maybe the question was meant to be: in how many ways can this distribution take place if we only discern the gender of human beings. If so then the question is badly worded. This should have been mentioned explicitly.

Comment: I think my answer holds because of Vandermonde's Identity, the number of males and females doesn't matter because if we split it up into two sub-samples and sum, you end up getting this as the answer.

Comment: We don't even need Vandermonde's Identity for this. It is immediately clear that  your answer is correct if human beings are supposed to be distinguishable. A split up in females/males (or any other) does not affect that. If the question is well worded then this split up was only meant to spread some confusion that had to be overcome. You did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result looks good.

Another way to obtain the same result is as follows:

- Any arrangement of the $20$ students can be interpreted as a possible assignment of grades: $20!$
- Now, cancel out the permutations among each group of students who get the same grade: $5!\cdot 6!\cdot 5!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!$

All together:
$$\frac{20!}{5!\cdot 6!\cdot 5!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!}$$

Comment: Isn't this the same as the multinomial coefficient?

Comment: Yes. It is. :-)